# Is it good practice to fetch user data and save it to Context on every call in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, react-context

I decided to use React's ContextAPI to store authenticated user data.
I've implemented a custom App component and wrote a `getInitialProps` function to retrieve user's data from the backend.

```
class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, authenticated, user } = this.props;
    return (
      <AuthProvider authenticated={authenticated}>
        <UserProvider userData={user}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </UserProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    );
  }
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  let authenticated = false;
  let user = null
  const request = appContext.ctx.req;
  if (request) {
    request.cookies = cookie.parse(request.headers.cookie || '');
    authenticated = !!request.cookies.sessionid;
    if (authenticated){
      user = await getCurrentUserData(request.headers.cookie)
    }
  }

  // Call the page's `getInitialProps` and fill `appProps.pageProps`
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

  return { ...appProps, authenticated, user };
};

export default MyApp;
```

What's concerns me the most is that `getCurrentUserData` is called every time a page is being rendered, so there is always one extra API call.

Is it good practice to do so?
Should I store user's data in a cookie, and update context from there?
How can I optimize this solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to be called for every page. You can create HoC for the Auth.. and use this HoC only for the page that use the user data.

usually the page that don't need user data is static page which is quite situational most of the time.

Comment: Problem is that I need it on every page since I'm always rendering a navbar, which needs this information.

Comment: It is already a good practice. you save all the user data in DB.